# Shell Script : How use find expression in a for?

Tags: linux, shell, debian, script, shell-script

I would like to use the `find` command in a `for`.
So I did this:

```
for logs in `find $BACKUP_FOLDER -exec ls -la {} \; | awk '{ if ( $8==2011) printf $0"\n" }'`; do
// some command here
done;
```

But it seems to not be working, so if I try to find out how the command is being interpreated, I put this line alone in my script:

```
echo "$BACKUP_FOLDER -exec ls -la {} \; | awk { if ( '$8'==2011) printf $0"\n" }";
```

And the `$8` appears blank and the `\n` is blank too.
This is what is printed in terminal

```
/company-logs/engine -exec ls -la {} \; | awk { if ( ''==2011) printf /company/scripts/server/backup/sync_backup.shn }
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Your question

```
echo "$BACKUP_FOLDER -exec ls -la {} \; | awk { if ( '$8'==2011) printf $0"\n" }";
```

won't display anything useful for two reasons:

- In order to see the command as it would get executed by the shell, you have to escape the special characters `$` and `"` with a backslash.
- `$8` is just the eighth command-line argument for bash. To see what awk would replace it with, execute this command instead:

  ```
  find $BACKUP_FOLDER -exec ls -la {} \; | awk '{ if ( $8==2011) printf $0"\n" }'
  ```

#### Your approach

Your for loop doesn't work since `printf $0` prints an entire line from `ls -l` (containing permissions, owners, date and time).

To fix this, you have to eliminate all but the bare file name using, e.g., awk itself or cut:

```
for logs in `find "$BACKUP_FOLDER" -exec ls -la {} \; | awk '{ if ( $8==2011) print $0 }' | cut -c 43-`; do ... done
```

This will create problems if there are spaces in the filenames. Setting the internal file separator to new-line only (`IFS=$'\n'` in bash) should take care of spaces.

#### Your problem

Your approach isn't very portable, since a different version of ls or a different locale might alter the fields.

To process all files from 2011, instead of your approach, I'd use

```
for logs in $(find "$BACKUP_FOLDER" -exec bash -c '[[ "$(stat -c %y "$0")" =~ ^2011 ]]' {} \; -print); do ... done
```

or, if possible,

```
find "$BACKUP_FOLDER" -exec bash -c '[[ "$(stat -c %y "$0")" =~ ^2011 ]]' {} \; -exec ... \;
```

Again, modifying the IFS should take care of spaces, but the second approach will be more reliable.

`find` replaces `{}` with the currently processed file and passes it as an argument to bash, which can access it as `$0`.

`stat -c %y "$0"` shows the modification time of `$0` and `[[ "$(...)" =~ ^2011 ]]` checks if it begins with `2011`.

If it does, `bash -c '...'` returns true and `-print` prints the filename or `-exec` executes a command.